# How can data be stored securely from backend code in node-red?

Tags: node.js, credentials, node-red

My use case is that I retrieve a OAuth refresh token from an OAuth server. I want to store this in the credentials of a config node in node-red. However I can't find how to do that.

On the [Node-RED credentials documentation page](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/credentials) I've found something that exactly describes my use case:

> Whilst the credential system outlined above is sufficient for most cases, in some circumstances it is necessary to store more values in credentials than just those that get provided by the user.
> For example, for a node to support an OAuth workflow, it must retain server-assigned tokens that the user never sees. The Twitter node provides a good example of how this can be achieved.

However, I have analyzed the [source code of the Twitter node](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/blob/master/social/twitter/27-twitter.js), but I couldn't find anything that updates the tokens from the backend code.

How can I store the token from the backend code (node.js parts of the Node-RED node) into the credentials field of the configuration node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to update stored credentials directly from the backend.

The only option would be to update the flow with the new credentials by POSTing to the Admin API but at best this would cause any nodes using those credentials to be restarted so any inflight messages may be lost.

It is a known edge case, but I'm not aware of any planned solution at this time.